# WPF Datagrid Binding to ICollection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, prism, mef

i hope you can help me, because I've an very special question.

I have an View with an Datagrid. The DataContext I generate Dynamically. This is done by resolving some Interface (lets say `IMyDataContext`) over MEF.

This Interface has some Properties. The interesting Property for this problem is

```
ICollection Data {get;}
```

This Property is Implemented in the Backend by an ObservableCollection of an type which is known in the class which implements the Interface.

Now the Problem is, that the DataGrid don't Generate the columns. Even if I Listen to the IPropertyChanged Event of the Specific Class and then Update the Layout. Nothing changes.

So my Question is, how can I resolve this Issue?

Or is there an better Solution for my Problem?
I also tried to make the Interface Generic so that it looks like the following:

```
public Interface IMyDataContext<CollectionType>
{
  ObservableCollection<CollectionType> Data {get;}
}
```

The Implementing Class Exports then with `[Export(typeof(IMyDataContext<>)]` or `[Export(typeof(IMyDataContext<object>)]`

and the class which registers the View with the DataContext via PRISM resolves them with `[ImportMany(typeof(IMyDataContext<object>)]` but this don't work with an ObservableCollection.

So this is why I declared the Collection as `ICollection` in the Interface.

Can someone explain me why it's not generating the Columns?

The Code for Binding in the View:

```
<DataGrid 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Data, UpdateSourceTrigger= PropertyChanged}"
                      CanUserAddRows="False"
                      CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                     ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader" />
```

// **Edit**:
I've checked that the Data are there. And yes they are available in the View. Other ViewElements which binds also on this Data Field works perfectly. And they are directly below the Datagrid.
Example (Pseudo Code):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" /> <!-- Dont work -->
<Label Content="No Data Available" IsVisible="{Binding Data, Convert={StaticResource CollectionIsEmptyToVisibleConverter}" /> <!-- Work -->
```

For Information:

I fill the collection at once in an other Thread. But to be Thread Safe I Use the Dispatcher like this:

```
var items  = new List<MyItemType>(); // MyItemType is an Class. this class I want to Display in the Datagrid

// ... fill items

Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>  this.Data = new ObservableCollection<MyItemType>(items)));
```

// **Edit 2**: 
Ok, here is a code Example:

The Interface which i Mean:

```
public interface IDataContextInterface: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ICollection Data { get; }
    // ... Some other Properties
}
```

An Example Implementation of the Interface (I have multiple Implementations):

```
[Export(typeof(IDataContextInterface))]
public class ExampleDataContext1 : IDataContextInterface
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyExampleDatagridEntry> _data;

    public ObservableCollection<object> Data
    {
        get
        {
            return this._data;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._data == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (value == null)
            {
                this._data = null;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Data");
                return;
            }

            var values = value.OfType<MyExampleDatagridEntry>();
            if (values != null)
            {

                this._data = new ObservableCollection<MyExampleDatagridEntry>(values);
            }
            else
            {
                this._data = null;
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged("Data");
        }
    }

    // Will be called in an Background Thread
    public void Update()
    {
        var data = new ObservableCollection<MyExampleDatagridEntry>();

        // .. fill the data

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    this._data =data));
    }
}
```

The Data for this Example Model looks like:

```
public class MyExampleDatagridEntry : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private _exampleString1;
    public string ExampleString1
    {
        get
        {
            return this._exampleString1;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._exampleString1 != value)
            {
                this._exampleString1 = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ExampleString1");
            }
        }
    }

    private _exampleString2;
    public string ExampleString2
    {
        get
        {
            return this._exampleString2;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._exampleString2 != value)
            {
                this._exampleString2 = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ExampleString2");
            }
        }
    }

    // .. Some other Properties
}
```

The Module which import all of them and register an new View to the Region (I don't know if there is a better way):

```
[ModuleExport(typeof(MyViewModule))]
public class MyViewModule : IModule
{
    private ObservableCollection<IDataContextInterface> _dataContextModels;
    private IRegionManager _regionManager;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MyViewModule(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        this._regionManager = regionManager;
        this.DataContextModels.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => this.UpdateViews();
    }

    [ImportMany(typeof(IDataContextInterface))]
    public ObservableCollection<IDataContextInterface> DataContextModels
    {
        get
        {
            return this._dataContextModels ?? (this._dataContextModels = new ObservableCollection<IDataContextInterface>());
        }
        set
        {
            this._dataContextModels = value;
            this.UpdateViews();
        }
    }

     private void UpdateViews()
     {
        foreach (var dataContext in this.DataContextModels)
        { 
            // Short version of it. Normally i check if its registered
            var view = new MyViewForDataContext{ dataContext = dataContext };
            this._regionManager.Regions["MyRegion"].Add(view);

        }
     }
}
```

And finally the View looks like this (Shorten to have it simpler):

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyViewForDataContext">
<!-- Some Other stuff here -->
    <Grid>
        <!-- This Datagrid don't generate the Columns -->
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
        <!-- This one works -->
        <Label Content="No Data Available" Visibility={Binding Data, Converter={StaticResource EmptyListToVisiblityConverter}} />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

### // Edit 3 (*Solution*):

Ok I finally solved it. It was an Problem by my behavior which I bound to the Datagrid. In this Behavior I tried to refresh the Datagrid, which worked fine. But not if the ItemsSource is null of the Datagrid. For this reason i had to insert an null check of the ItemsSource.

Comment: Provide a minimalistic project illustrating your problem

Comment: @netaholic Ok I've tried to keep it simple. But well... PRISM is not that easy to keep it simple